# How to transfer elements of 1 vector into another vector?

Tags: c++, malloc, playing-cards

I am learning C++ and decided to make a card deck system using vectors. I have been able to randomly shuffle it, make 1 singular deck, and now I want to make a function that deals a hand from that deck.

Say I wanted a hand of 10 cards from a deck of 52 cards, therefore 42 cards would be left and the first 10 cards of the Deck vector will be taken and placed into the `newHand` vector but after looking for solutions on how to approach this using `erase()` and `pop_back()`, I cant seem to find an efficient or proper solution. However since I am new to C++ my code might not be the best thing to look at so I am open for suggestions on how to make this better, maybe with pointers? (Pointers are confusing to me and I am not sure when to use them).

Here are the main functions:

```
void Deck::deleteElement(std::vector<std::string> Deck, int index)
{
    while (index--) {
        Deck.erase(Deck.begin(), Deck.begin() + index);
    }
}

void Deck::dealHand(int numOfCards, std::vector<std::string>& currentDeck, int numOfDecks)
{
    std::vector<std::string> newHand;
    static int remaining = deckSize(numOfDecks);

    while (numOfCards-- && remaining != 0) {
        newHand.push_back(currentDeck[numOfCards]);
        --remaining;
    } deleteElement(currentDeck, numOfCards);

    for (auto & i : newHand) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << ",there are now " << remaining << " cards remaining" << std::endl;
}
```

I want to mention that `deleteElement` when using erase gives me this error

```
 malloc: *** error for object 0x16f9ddf40: pointer being freed was not allocated
 malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I also could not find much on explaining what this means, if anyone can that would be a great help.

Comment: The bug in `deleteElement` is obvious, however even after it's fixed you will discover that `deleteElement` will never delete anything, at all, whatsoever. Do you understand the difference between passing function parameters by value, versus by reference? Can you describe, in your own words, what you expect `deleteElement` to do?

Comment: The static variable in `dealHand` is a huge red flag, unless you want a completely non-reusable object. If you really want a deck where you only deal off the top, a `std::stack` might be a more appropriate structure. Then just pop however many cards you want. It's unclear what `currentDeck` and `numOfDecks` is supposed to represent. If you really have a "Deck" object, then why are you passing other types into some function and calling those "decks"? A "Deck" should be initialized when constructed, and provide basic methods such as "shuffle", "split", "insert" and "draw" as required.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I wanted delete element to delete the first n elements of the deck since I wanted to grab the first n elements of said deck, put it in the new hand and go from there.

Comment: @paddy I just wanted to test something irrelevant to the question, numOfDecks is not and will not be included into the dealHand function

Comment: @Cr3D -- C++ is not Java.  When you pass types like you're doing, you are *not* passing references to the object -- instead you are passing *copies*.  This is a **major** difference between C++ and whatever other languages you are familiar with.  If you want to pass a reference in C++, you must *explicitly* state so by using the reference parameter `void Deck::deleteElement(std::vector<std::string>& Deck, int index)`.  And to that -- if you're using Java, JavaScript, or some other language as a model in writing C++ code, don't do this.  All that will happen are the mistakes you're making now.

Comment: Grabbing the last elements would be better with a vector as you can then just `resize` without having to shift the remaining cards to the front.

Comment: Apart from that I think the best you can do is reserve space in the destination and then iterate over all elements and `dst.emplace_back(std::move(src[i]))`. Although you probably gain more by defining cards as a struct of kind and value than having them as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably not bother with actually erasing elements from the deck's internal vector. That's because you might want to reshuffle and deal cards multiple times over the course of a game, which is easier if you just keep them all in the deck and track which ones have been dealt. And since almost everything container-related uses iterators, you can keep it short and simple like this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class Card {};

class Deck {
public:
    using Cards = std::vector<Card>;

    // Just an example constructor
    explicit Deck(std::size_t size = 52)
        : m_cards(size), m_current{m_cards.begin()}
    {}

    Cards dealHand(std::size_t count) {
        auto begin = m_current;
        std::ranges::advance(m_current, count, m_cards.end());
        return Cards(begin, m_current);
    }

    std::size_t
    size() const { return std::ranges::distance(m_current, m_cards.end()); }

private:
    Cards m_cards;
    Cards::iterator m_current;
};

int main() {
    Deck deck {};
    auto hand = deck.dealHand(10);
    return deck.size();
}
```

While it's not strictly necessary to use std::ranges functions (they have equivalents in the std namespace), this part of C++20 is now widely supported. One advantage is that range algorithms accept entire ranges (such as containers) instead of only pairs of iterators, for example [`std::ranges::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/shuffle).

Comment: Why do you use the keyword explicit? And when do you recommend using it? Other than that thank you.

Comment: @Cr3D It's because constructors that can be called with one argument will normally act as implicit conversion operators. So, if for example Deck had an `operator==`, it would then allow comparison with any value that is convertible to `std::size_t`, by constructing a temporary Deck from it. That's not usually what you want, so you should prevent it by [making the constructor explicit](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c46-by-default-declare-single-argument-constructors-explicit).